# Edge angle as node property in a material

Tags: materials, node-editor, edges

I am looking for a way to get worn edges as a procedural material. I have tried the ambient occlusion method, and I have also tried the "pointiness" property in the geometry node. However I don't find them satisfying.

In the viewport overlays there is a setting where you can view any edges angle.
[image]

I am looking for a way to get this value as some for of input in the material editor. Is this possible?! Thank you :)

Comment: Not directly, the closest you can get is *Pointiness*

Comment: Bevel node -> Math Absolute node.